# How to change the default icon pin on leaflet directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, directive, angular-leaflet-directive

I want to know if is possible change the default icon (blue), with another custom icon when the app is initialized, I read about how to change but I want a custom icon for the entire app.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="CustomizedMarkersController">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary padright" ng-click="markers.m1.icon=icon" ng-repeat="(key, icon) in icons">{{ key }}</button>
   <leaflet markers="markers" center="lisbon"></leaflet>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.controller("CustomizedMarkersController", [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    var local_icons = {
       default_icon: {},
       leaf_icon: {
          iconUrl: 'examples/img/leaf-green.png',
          shadowUrl: 'examples/img/leaf-shadow.png',
          iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
          shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
          iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
          shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
          popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open         relative to the iconAnchor
       },
       div_icon: {
           type: 'div',
           iconSize: [230, 0],
           html: 'Using <strong>Bold text as an icon</strong>: Lisbon',
           popupAnchor:  [0, 0]
       },
       orange_leaf_icon: {
          iconUrl: 'examples/img/leaf-orange.png',
          shadowUrl: 'examples/img/leaf-shadow.png',
          iconSize:     [38, 95],
          shadowSize:   [50, 64],
          iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
          shadowAnchor: [4, 62]
       }
 };

angular.extend($scope, {
    icons: local_icons
});

angular.extend($scope, {
    lisbon: {
        lat: 38.716,
        lng: -9.13,
        zoom: 8
    },
    markers: {
        m1: {
            lat: 38.716,
            lng: -9.13,
            message: "I'm a static marker",
            icon: local_icons.default_icon,
        },
    },
    defaults: {
        scrollWheelZoom: false
    }
});
}]);
```

[Based on this example.](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/customized-markers)

Answer (score 7):

From the [Leaflet documentation, see `Icon.Default`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#icon-default):

> In order to change the default icon, just change the properties of `L.Icon.Default.prototype.options` (which is a set of `Icon options`).

E.g., include a line in your code that is:

```
L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.iconUrl = 'myNewDefaultImage.png';
```

You will probably also want to change the shadows and 2x icon for retina displays, which are set with options `shadowUrl` and `iconRetinaUrl`.

Comment: I just found this answer and no one accepted this as the correct answer so I will.  This example script updated the default icon with my custom new icon to replace the default.  Thank you user2441511.

Comment: I wanted to hide the icon, since it was being used by the Leaflet-Draw plugin whenever you were in editing mode. Setting these variables to `null` displayed a broken image. If you want to hide the icon completely you can set `L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.iconSize = [0, 0];` and 
`L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.shadowSize = [0, 0];`

Comment: I think it's a little bit too much of hack to overwrite the prototype itself. I would advice to use `mergeOptions` instead. For more details have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6):

As the above solution did not work for me while using Leaflet-1.7,
I was successful using this approach:

```
L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: "/path/to/markericon.png",
    shadowUrl: "/path/to/markershadow.png"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for customize draw plugins

```
var drawPluginOptions = {
  position: 'topright',
  draw: {
    polyline: false,
    polygon: false,
    circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
    rectangle: false,
    circlemarker: false,
    marker: {
    title: "markerTest",
      icon: new MyCustomMarker()
    }
  },
  edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
    remove: false
  }
};
```

and add to map

````
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;
    
    /*if(layer.title == "Place hospital marker"){
        do this...
    }*/

  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

The by leaflet advised way to achieve this, is using [`mergeOptions`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#class-mergeoptions). I think one shouldn't hack the `prototype` directly, as stated in many answers here, since we are overwriting the internals of library, which might change one day.

```js
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions(icons)
```

For `icons` being:

```js
icons = { // you can replace with your exact image paths
  iconUrl: 'media/images/marker-icon.png', 
  iconRetinaUrl: 'media/images/marker-icon-2x.png',
  shadowUrl: 'media/images/marker-shadow.png',
}
```

You can refer [Icon doc](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) for all available options on `Icon.default` set within `icons`.